# std::future implementation for gcc 4.6

Tags: android, c++, gcc, c++11, android-ndk

I have cross platform C++11 code, which I would like to compile on Android. While most trivial code compiles on *ndk8b* or *CrystaX7*, `std::future` is sadly not yet available. Is there any (partial/crude) implementation of `std::future` for *gcc4.6*?

The best option I can think of right now is to port `std::future` from libstdc++4.7 or libc++.

Comment: You might be able to use [boost::future](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures) (which is pretty similar).

Comment: Another possibility is http://www.stdthread.co.uk.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I'm pretty sure `just::thread` only supports x86 targets (but it's worth investigation).

Comment: Isn't `std::future` a header-only template?

Comment: @KerrekSB Not only - part of it is built into libstdc++ libraries. Besides it depends upon quite a few other headers.